# Programmatically determining how many element to display in a web navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have a horizontal navigation bar that can have an arbitrary number of items in it.  Now let say this page has a width of 1000px and all the items if displayed would be 1300px.  Now what I would want to do is to take whatever elements are causing it to extend beyond the 1000px and put them into a drop down menu.  The issue I am having is what is the best way to figure out how many element I would need to take to make sure everything fits in the window when the window width can be changed (if the user changes the window width, the number of elements in the drop down would increase or decrease) and the navigation element widths are random?

Something similar to google plus's side navigation, just horizontal instead fo vertical.

Comment: Are they all the same size?

Comment: That is the problem, they are not the same size.  For example, one might be Users however another might be User Groups and each of those would take up a different width natively.  Google plus might be doing simple math since each item is the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Put the navigation elements in a parent div whose overflow is set to hidden so the extra nav elements are hidden.
Then, find the items that are hidden using jquery and append them to your dropdown menu. See answer to this question: [jQuery: How to get content not visible with overflow: hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731101/jquery-how-to-get-content-not-visible-with-overflow-hidden)

See my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zSXTb.  The basics:

```
var h = $("#container").height();
$("#container").find("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).position().top > h) {
        $(this).clone().appendTo($("#extrasContent"));
    }
});
```

Run this onload and when the window is resized.

Comment: This for me a the last resorts.  It would be nice if I would do it without having to make each element a specific width but if I have to, I will.

Comment: You dont need to make each a specific width. See this JSFiddle, does exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/zSXTb/

Answer (score 0):

Try using @media queries with the css - you get a lot of control regarding screen size. For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px){
    /*insert normal css. e.g.:*/
    body{
        width: 700px;
    }
}
```

You can use *min-width* instead of *max-width*.