# jQuery get count of Overflow hidden elements

Tags: jquery

I have a ul with many li in it and have given a height to the ul with overflow hidden, now I need to find either the number elements which have not gone overflown or which have overflown. I tried using length() function, but it returns all li count

```
<ul id="am-container" class="am-container thumbs noscript" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
<li id="1" class="image-in">
<li id="4" class="image-in">
<li id="5" class="image-in">
<li id="6" class="image-in">
<li id="7" class="image-in">
<li id="8" class="image-in">
<li id="9" class="image-in">
<li id="10" class="image-in">
<li id="11" class="image-in">
<li id="12" class="image-in">
<li id="13" class="image-in">
<li id="14" class="image-in">
<li id="15" class="image-in">
<li id="16" class="image-in">
<li id="17" class="image-in">
<li id="18" class="image-in">
<li id="23" class="image-in">
<li id="24" class="image-in">
<li id="25" class="image-in">
<li id="26" class="image-in">
<li id="30" class="image-in">
<li id="33" class="image-in">
<li id="34" class="image-in">
<li id="35" class="image-in">
<li id="36" class="image-in">
<li id="38" class="image-in">
<li id="39" class="image-in">
<li id="40" class="image-in">
<li id="41" class="image-in">
<li id="42" class="image-in">
<li id="43" class="image-in">
<li id="44" class="image-in">
<li id="45" class="image-in">
<li id="46" class="image-in">
<li id="47" class="image-in">
<li id="52" class="image-in">
<li id="53" class="image-in">
<li id="54" class="image-in">
<li id="55" class="image-in">
</ul>
```

css :

```
.am-container.thumbs {
    max-height: 365px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**ANSWER**

this worked perfect for me by using both the answers provided:

```
var hiddenEls = new Array();

        $("#am-container").find("li").each(function(){
            if ($(this).position().top < $("#am-container").position().top + 275)
                hiddenEls.push($(this));
        });
        var numrow = hiddenEls.length;
```

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt so easy,

You need to compare the position of each element to the height of the document (body):

```
var h = $("body").height();
var hiddenEls = new Array();

$("#am-container").find("li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).position().top > h)
        hiddenEls.push($(this));
});
alert (hiddenEls.length);
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/XWK94/4/)

Comment: huh! totally confused with the quesiton so I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: @C-link please refer [jQuery: How to get content not visible with overflow: hidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731101/jquery-how-to-get-content-not-visible-with-overflow-hidden)

Comment: @Pilot thankyou it went perfect with some changes taking from the answer from user2594825

Comment: Please give his answer a Vote Up, cause that also helped.

Answer (score 5):

You can find number `li` elements shown in page using this,

```
var maxh = $("ul.am-container").height();

console.log($("ul.am-container li").filter(function () {
    return $(this).position().top + $(this).height() < maxh;

}).length);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it helped a lot, unfortunately I can accept only one answer

Answer (score 0):

> Another Way
>
> HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Nageshwar</li>  
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Nageshwar</li>  
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>Jquery</li></ul>
```

> Total Hidden Elements: 15
>
> CSS

```
ul{
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;}
```

> JQuery

```
var len,count;
len=parseInt($("li").height());
count=$("li").length;
var hiddenHeight=(len*count)-($("ul").height());
hiddenHeight=parseInt(hiddenHeight);
var hiddenLi=hiddenHeight/len;
hiddenLi=Math.ceil(hiddenLi);
$("#count").html(hiddenLi);
```